# HierarchicalDataTemplate applied on Field/Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

is it possible to apply a HierarchicalDataTemplate to a Property?
I know i can apply it to a DataType, that works perfectly, but what if i have an generic Class, and the only distinguishable Element is a enum in this class. 
So can i somehow apply a different HierarchicalDataTemplate on the value of the enum??

Greets,

Jürgen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `DataTemplateSelector`. Please see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#Styling_StyleSelection. There is an example of how to choose a template based on properties of the data object.

Comment: Perfekt, excatly what i was looking for. THX!